# Where can I get a battery replacement for a PS3 controller and how can I replace it?

Tags: ps3, controllers

Is there any way to change the battery of a PS3 controller? If so, where do I get a new one!? and how do I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search Google for [ps3 controller replacement battery](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&q=ps3+controller+replacement+battery) you'll find plenty of places selling them online, including Amazon. They may carry them in Gamestop if you prefer brick&mortar stores.

As for *how* to replace it, here is [a YouTube video demonstrating the process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWk4MBiu0a4). Looks fairly straight-forward.

When I was searching for these things I found an old Joystiq article where a Sony rep says that [Sony will replace PS3 controllers if/when they die](http://www.joystiq.com/2006/10/20/sony-to-replace-ps3-controllers-when-if-they-die/). This article was written before the PS3 released though, so I don't know if they included that in their official terms of service or not.